# Google Script - Compare file name to folder name and move file in to folder if name matches

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to compare my google drive folder names to some file names and then if there is a match - move the file to the respective folder.

i.e -

folders:
example1,
example2,
example3,

files:
example1.jpg (move to folder - example1),
example2.jpg (move to folder - example2),
example3.jpg (move to folder - example3)

So far I have two arrays with the folder and file names which I am looping over and comparing the two.

I'm struggling with the next bit - moving the file to the folder.

This is what I've got so far...

```js
function folderAndFiles(){

  var fileArray = [];
  var folderArray = [];

  var dApp = DriveApp;
  var folderIter = dApp.getFoldersByName("files");
  var folder = folderIter.next();
  var fileIter = dApp.getFiles();
  var filesIter = folder.getFiles();



  while(filesIter.hasNext()) {
    var file = filesIter.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    fileArray.push(fileName)

  }

  fileArray.sort();
  var newFiles = fileArray.map(function(d) { return d.replace('.jpg', ''); });
  Logger.log(newFiles);



  var folderIterTwo = dApp.getFoldersByName("names");
  var folderTwo = folderIterTwo.next();
  var nameFolders = folderTwo.getFolders();



  while(nameFolders.hasNext()) {
    var folders =  nameFolders.next();
    var names = folders.getName();
    folderArray.push(names)

  }

  folderArray.sort();
  Logger.log(folderArray);



  for (var i = 0; i < folderArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < newFiles.length; j++) {
        if (folderArray[i] == newFiles[j]) {
         folderArray[i].addFile(fileArray[i]);
          Logger.log("Moved");
        }
    }
  }


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to store the actual FileObject *and* its name, along with the FolderObject and its name. Otherwise you will need to re-find the FolderObject and FileObject having the target names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code below:

```js
function folderAndFiles(){
  var files = [];
  var folderMap = {};

  var foldersParent = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("names").next();
  var filesParent = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("files").next();

  var filesIterator = filesParent.getFiles();
  var foldersIterator = foldersParent.getFolders();

  while(filesIterator.hasNext()) {
    var currentFile = filesIterator.next();
    files.push(currentFile);
  }

  while(foldersIterator.hasNext()) {
    var currentFolder =  foldersIterator.next();
    folderMap[currentFolder.getName()] = currentFolder;
  }

  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    var fileName = file.getName().replace('.jpg', '');
    var destinationFolder = folderMap[fileName];

    if (destinationFolder) {
      destinationFolder.addFile(files[i]);
      filesParent.removeFile(file);
      Logger.log("Moved");
    }
  }
}
```

The flow of the program is the following:

1. Create a list with all the files to move.
2. Create a [dictionary](https://pietschsoft.com/post/2015/09/05/javascript-basics-how-to-create-a-dictionary-with-keyvalue-pairs) that maps the names of the folders to the actual [folder object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder).
3. For each file:

   1. Compute its name (remove the extension).
   2. Check whether there is a folder with that name.
   3. In case there is, **move** the file in question to that folder.

Note that the file is actually moved - it is added to the new folder, but also removed from the original one. If you want to just copy it, remove the line `filesParent.removeFile(file);` of the code.

Comment: @Richhawk106 As a guideline, you could call the `getFolders()` method of your folder to obtain its subfolders, and then retrieve the name with `getName()` and compare it using [`indexOf()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp). However, if you still have issues doing so I recommend you create a brand new question. Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

This should be a partial solution, which will help you implement the rest:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} [parentFolderName] Name of the folder within which to search (defaults to Drive root)
 * @returns {Array <{ name: string, file: File }>} an array of objects with the properties 'name' (containing a string) and 'file' (containing the File object reference)
 */
function getNamedDriveFiles_(parentFolderName) {
  var parent = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  if (parentFolderName) {
    var matches = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(parentFolderName);
    if (!matches.hasNext()) {
      throw new Error('No folder with name "' + parentFolderName + '"');
    }
    parent = matches.next();
  }
  const results = [];
  var iterator = parent.getFiles();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = iterator.next();
    // Store an object with the name of the file, and the File object itself
    results.push({ name: file.getName(), file: file });
  }
  return results;
}

function doStuff() {
  const files = getNamedDriveFiles_('my cool folder');
  files.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.name < b.name;
  });
  // print filesizes
  files.forEach(function (obj) {
    Logger.log('Filename: "' + obj.name + '"; size: ' + obj.file.getSize());
  });
}
```

You should be able to implement a similar function for your folder objects, and then can easily reference the File and Folder for a given filename and foldername.